# Here Map setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath returns `false`

Tags: android, here-api

I am following [this official](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/app-create-simple.html) tutorial. I am facing a problem for setting disk cache root path. I am using Here Map inside a Fragment. Here is the code i am using.

```
mapFragment = (AndroidXMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
String  diskCacheRoot = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + ".here-maps";

boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
            diskCacheRoot,
            getString(R.string.hereMapServiceIntentName)); 

if (!success){
   Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to set isolated disk cache path.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
   // initialize map
}
```

For the first time i am getting `success` true. When i come back this `Fragment` again `success` is always false.

From official documentation for `setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath` method

> Returns:
>
> false if path matches default disk cache path or path is a file or
>   invalid or is not writable or intentAction matches default service
>   connection name, otherwise true.

Not sure for which case i am getting `false`.

If i clear my app from recent and relaunch again then First time i got `success` true.

Can anyone can explain the scenario why this is happening.

Comment: Which version of the HERE Mobile SDK are you using?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport i'a using 3.14.2 verison

Comment: Alright, thanks for reporting this. We will look into it and get back to you soon.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the Files Directory method working now. Using `getFilesDir` instead of `getExternalFilesDir` is working for me.

```
String  diskCacheRoot = getContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separator + ".here-maps";
```

[Andrew's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680639/1292557) suggestion is also working for me.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs for me since 3.13.x too, and worked before 3.13.x.

Comment: Can you upgrade to version 3.14 and check if issue still persists please.

Comment: It still persists with 3.14.2. The 1st time setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath is successful, the 2nd time not. So it's not possible to interrupt and continue a navigation and we can't update from 3.12.88 to a higher version.

Comment: Alright, thanks for reporting this. We will look into it and get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/MapSettings.html

It is said:

> The method must be called before the init() methods on MapEngine.

You cannot run this method after mapEngine is initialised.
To fix this use the following logic:

```
if (!MapEngine.isInitialized()) {
    MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(diskCacheRoot, ISOLATED_MAP_SERVICE_INTENT);
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about sdk premium 3.14.2 ?
Method setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath() is deprecated ...

https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/MapSettings.html#setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

```
@Deprecated
@HybridPlus
public static boolean setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(String var0, String var1) {
    return com.nokia.maps.MapSettings.b(var0, var1);
}
```